# Comparacion de dos archivos .txt y generacion de un archivo resultante en .csv

Tags: python, csv, txt

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Phyton, me pidieron generar un archivo .csv que parte de una comparación de dos archivos .txt.

En mi archivo principal `File1` tiene lineas con dos datos separados por una coma (ID, Nombre_de_archivo).

En mi archivo secundario tengo solo nombre de archivo.

Lo que necesito es barrer cada linea del `File1` y ver si está en el F2.

Como resultado final debería generar un archivo .csv que tenga los mismos datos que tiene el F1 mas un tercer dato que deberia ser el resultado del barrido, es decir un yes o no de si esta o no en el F2.

Hasta los momentos hago el barrido pero solo me toma el primera linea del f1 despues de eso no pareciera que siguiera y tampoco he logrado que me genere el csv.

Añado algo del codigo

```
f = open("recordings.txt", "r")
g = open("destino.txt", "w")
separador = ","
for lineas in f.readlines():
    f2 = open("archivoscloud1.txt", "r")
    separado = lineas.split(separador)
    for lineas2 in f2.readlines():
        if (separado[1]) == lineas2:
            g.write("yes," + separado[0] + "," + separado[1])
            break
    else:
        g.write("no," + separado[0] + "," + separado[1])
    f2.close()
f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: Tienes que plantear una pregunta de código.

Comment: Ya logre que barriera bien el archivo pero se esta tardando mucho en terminar, adicional aun no se como generar el csv.

Comment: Si has conseguido que funcione, entonces ¿cuál es la pregunta? No sabemos cómo son de grandes los ficheros. ¿Puedes dar una estimación de cuántas líneas tiene cada uno y si estas líneas están ordenadas?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar en una cadena el archivo `file2`, que contiene solo los nombres de archivo. Luego recorres `file1` y verificas si el nombre_de_archivo por cada línea está contenido en los datos de `file2`.

> File1 tiene lineas con dos datos separados por una coma (ID,
> Nombre_de_archivo).

*file1.txt*

```
350,archivo_08
482,archivo_25
510,archivo_32
725,archivo_92
```

> archivo secundario tengo solo nombre de archivo

*file2.txt*

```
archivo_25
archivo_92
```

El código sería:

```py
todos_nomb_archivos = ''
with open('file2.txt') as f2:
    todos_nomb_archivos = f2.read()

with open('result.txt', 'w') as res:
    with open('file1.txt') as f1:
        for line in f1.readlines():
            clean_line = line.strip()
            nom_arch = clean_line.split(',')[1]
            if nom_arch in todos_nomb_archivos:
                res.write(clean_line + ',yes' + '\n')
            else:
                res.write(clean_line + ',no' + '\n')
```

Esto generará un archivo `result.txt` con la siguiente información:

```
350,archivo_08,no
482,archivo_25,yes
510,archivo_32,no
725,archivo_92,yes
```